# Failed to save snapshot by rhc

Tags: mysql, openshift, snapshot, openshift-client-tools

every time I run `rhc snapshot save wp1`  got this

```
        Pulling down a snapshot to wp1.tar.gz...
        Saving snapshot for secondary mysql-5.5 gear
        /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-   origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1313:in `block in do_control_with_directory': CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control pre-snapshot' for /var/lib/openshift/5322d44ce0b8cd3bbd0001cb/mysql (OpenShift::Runtime::Utils::ShellExecutionException)
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1114:in `process_cartridges'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1276:in `do_control_with_directory'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1136:in `do_control'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/snapshots.rb:68:in `block in snapshot'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:80:in `block in each_cartridge'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1120:in `block in process_cartridges'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1118:in `each'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1118:in `process_cartridges'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:78:in `each_cartridge'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/snapshots.rb:67:in `snapshot'
            from /usr/bin/gear:569:in `block (2 levels) in '
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:385:in `run_active_command'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:62:in `run!'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander

    /import.rb:10:in `block in '
```

```
    
        /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in oo_spawn': Shell command '/usr/bin/ssh -q -o 'BatchMode=yes' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -i

 $OPENSHIFT_APP_SSH_KEY  5322d44ce0b8cd3bbd0001cb@5322d44ce0b8cd3bbd0001cb-wpis.rhcloud.com 'snapshot' > mysql-5.5.tar.gz' returned an error. rc=1 (OpenShift::Runtime::Utils::ShellExecutionException)
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:96:in `pipe'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:96:in `block in oo_spawn'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:95:in `pipe'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:95:in `oo_spawn'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-container-selinux-0.7.1/lib/openshift/runtime/containerization/selinux_container.rb:339:in `run_in_container_context'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container.rb:764:in `run_in_container_context'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/snapshots.rb:104:in `block in handle_scalable_snapshot'                                                                                                                                
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/snapshots.rb:100:in `each'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/snapshots.rb:100:in `handle_scalable_snapshot'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.21.6/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container_ext/snapshots.rb:58:in `snapshot'
            from /usr/bin/gear:569:in `block (2 levels) in '
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:385:in `run_active_command'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:62:in `run!'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
            from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in '
    Error in trying to save snapshot. You can try to save manually by running:
    ssh ce2cf000931@wp1-wpis.rhcloud.com 'snapshot' > wp1.tar.gz
```

I try to restart my application,but not work.
ruby verison 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
rhc 1.21.3

am I doing something wrong?

``````

Answer (score 0):

Please file a bug report with the above details here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online